# ReactiveCocoa: observe a list of signals and call block when any signal post next message

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I have 3 properties to observe and when any one of them changes, I would like to call a same block.

I can't use combineLast:reduce: since there are times when only one of the three signals will generate next message.

Is there any good idea besides writing `RACObserve()` 3 times?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do that, that I can think of, would be by merging all three signals, so that every event is passed through in a single stream, like so:

```
[[RACSignal merge:@[RACObserve(self, property1),
                    RACObserve(self, property2),
                    RACObserve(self, property3)]] 
  subscribeNext:^(id x){
      NSLog(@"%@", x);
}]
```